# How to install azure.storage.blob library for python?

Tags: python, pip, blob, conda, azure-data-factory

I have issues while importing BlobServiceClient and BlobClient from azure.storage.blob library. I understood that my issue was related whith a conflict on versions. I am able to install the library with pip but then I have the first issue shown (1/). And when I try to install the library with conda (to manage the versions) I have the second error (2/).

Notes :
A) I tried to install/uninstall the library as mentionned in the other questions.
B) I tried to change the python version, I tested python 3.7, python 3.8 and python 3.10 without any success.

Thank you very much for your help !

Blandine

---

### ------------------- 1/ Error message when having installed the librairy with pip ----------------

**C:\WINDOWS\system32>python**
Python 3.8.8 (default, Apr 13 2021, 15:08:03) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32

Warning:
This Python interpreter is in a conda environment, but the environment has
not been activated.  Libraries may fail to load.  To activate this environment
please see https://conda.io/activation

Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> > > azure-storage-blob
> > > Traceback (most recent call last):
> > > File "", line 1, in 
> > > NameError: name 'azure' is not defined
> > > from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
> > > Traceback (most recent call last):
> > > File "", line 1, in 
> > > ImportError: cannot import name 'BlobServiceClient' from 'azure.storage.blob' (C:\Users\DBL1DY\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\azure\storage\blob_*init*_.py)

---

### ------------------- 2/ Error message when installing the library with conda ---------------------

**(python37) C:\WINDOWS\system32>conda install azure**
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: -
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:

Specifications:

- azure -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0']

Your python: python=3.7

If python is on the left-most side of the chain, that's the version you've asked for.
When python appears to the right, that indicates that the thing on the left is somehow
not available for the python version you are constrained to. Note that conda will not
change your python version to a different minor version unless you explicitly specify
that.

Answer (score 0):

> Specifications: • azure ->
> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0'] Your
> python: python=3.7

As clearly mentioned in the above error, Python version should be less than `3.7`

Please try Python version `3.6` or `3.5` or `2.8` or `2.7`

Comment: Hello, thank you for the comment, I did it already but still have the error. I manually install azure-storage-blob, and all when good after.